# regex for last XX numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, hyperlink, int

```
longURLorSTRING-2011-021243131612702
```

I need the output of the last 13 numbers of a string like above. But split isnt enough becouse the "..-2011-02.." may change sometimes

do someone know how to do that? the function should return the 13 numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var my_string = "longURLorSTRING-2011-021243131612702";
var my_new_string = my_string.substr((my_string.length - 13),13);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/rAJjk/

Comment: thanks thats the solution... i forgot its possible with substr too

Comment: @ggzone It's also possible using `my_string.slice(-13);` or `my_string.slice(-13);` (the last one does not work pretty well in IE).

Answer (score 4):

The Regex you are looking for should be

`\d{13}$`

The Substring method should work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

One regex to find the last 13 numbers of a string like that would be

```
/.*([0-9]{13})$/
```

The numbers you want would be in the first group.

Answer (score 0):

Why not search just for the 13 numbers at the end of a string?

```
/(.+)(\d{13})$/
```

The first `(.+)` is not really needed but you might need to capture it at some point so there's no real harm

(NB - The above is what I would use in PHP. Can't comment for JavaScript but it wouldn't be too different I imagine)